# How to change layout preview default devices on Android Studio

Tags: android, layout, preview, setting

When I create a new layout, the default device is Nexus 4. How can I change default device that when next time I create a new layout, the device will be Nexus 5, but NOT nexus 4.

Answer (score -1):

At least Android Studio 2.1.3 appears to honor the setting once you have changed it. As a test I created a new project in AS, opened the layout and changed the selection in the corresponding drop down list from Nexus 4 to Nexus 5. Closed the tab and reopened the layout: Nexus 5. Created a new layout (right click on the project node res/layout, New, Layout file): Nexus 5. Closed and reopened AS: same test as before: Nexus 5. With which AS version are you experienceing the issue?